# Handbook for Spoken mathematics Italian

Tags: reference-request, education, book-recommendation

I'm looking for something similar to the book [Handbook for spoken mathematics](http://englishlangkan.com/produk/E%20Book%20Handbook%20for%20Spoken%20Mathematics.pdf) to have all the rules to precisely dictate math formulas, but for the *italian* language. Unfortunately I didn't find anything. Do you know any similar book?

Thank you